# Dynamic form CodeIgniter, Attribute Form in Database

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter, dynamic

I want ask something about Code Igniter Dynamic Form.

I want to make a Form. Every tag like input, text area, etc, and attribute like id, class, etc of that Form stored in database. No hard code in html/php. Only fetch the attribute and tag from database, the Controller will load from database and send to View. And automatically will display the Form like what I saved in database.

In this case, the future of this form will be increased or reduced without need to hard coding by the developer.

Anyone can tell me how to make like that. And give reference link to me, so i can learn it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at this github project may help you to get the idea
[Generate a form from a DB table](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Generate-a-form-from-a-DB-table)